# Seeking all US 2010 Census Data at Tract Level

Tags: data, census, united-states

I'm trying to find where I can download all the data (summarized to the tract level).
By all data, I mean

- population
- race
- Marital status
- job
- wage
- age
- sex
- same sex couples
- kids
- education

**I need this for every tract, in every county, in every state.**

Every search I do shows someone asking for something like just population counts by block in 1 area. people are usually pointed to the American Fact Finder, but this is going to be too cumbersome for what I want.

I think I need the summary files, but haven't been able to find anything that shows, in clear detail, which ones I need.

Comment: Oh, and I'm looking for the 10 year files of the actual counts. Not the 1, 3, or 5 year, nor the estimates.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for does not exist. There is no 10-year file beyond 2000, and there has never been an "actual counts" data for jobs, wages, or education. What you are looking for is best obtained through American FactFinder, or NHGIS.org. I recommend [NHGIS](https://www.nhgis.org/) because its interface is easier to navigate. The most recent data available is the 2007-2011 ACS Summary File. The 2008-2012 is out, but you'll have to wait until NHGIS.org processes the data for public use, or use American FactFinder.

Answer (score 3):

This FTP:

http://www2.census.gov/

Has easily downloadable data for you. I believe the files you want are in Census 2010 -> Demographic Profile:

http://www2.census.gov/census_2010/03-Demographic_Profile/

Please note you'll need this file to understand the csvs you'll be downloading:

http://www2.census.gov/census_2010/03-Demographic_Profile/0FILE_STRUCTURE.doc

If you need to map the data you can get the cartographic files from here:

http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html

If you absolutely need the raw counts with no aggregation you'll have to wait until that data is released in 2080 (all raw census data is considered private and confidential for 70 years). Until then the most detailed you can get is data aggregated to the tract level.