# Population by Census Tract

Tags: data, census, population, united-states

I am looking to obtain count of population by census tract. The ideal output would be Census Tract 1919.01 Population = 7,435.

Does anyone know of resources where I can get this information. I tried searching Census.Gov w/ no luck.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81790/all-us-2010-census-data-tract-level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find the [TIGER](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html) page helpful in finding information. For instance, [this shapefile](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010DP1/Tract_2010Census_DP1.zip) purports to contain basic demographic information by 2010 Census Tract. There are other types of information you might find interesting as well.

If you want to find your own Census Tracts, you can use this user interface, known as the [American FactFinder](http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml?refresh=t) to find your area of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The Census Bureau also publishes csv files for tracts and many other geographies that contain the population centroid (aka Centers of Population) for each feature. In one download you'd have the Tract ID numbers, the 2010 Population, and the population centroid in Long / Lat (NAD 83) for each feature:

http://www.census.gov/geo/reference/centersofpop.html

Comment: I spent well over an hour searching the Census website for a simple tally of people per census tract. Lost in a sea of data about Native American Population distribution, Counties losing and gaining people and a zillion other factoids, I could not find the most basic information. This link was exactly what I needed! BTW - Thanks for naming the spatial coordinate system. In SQL Server, NAD83 has spatial_reference_id = 4269.